# Trying to combine multiple rows into one row with different values

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
item_code | whse_desc | Height | Width | Window
--------------------------------------------------
  WD123   |     KC    |  1.25  |  4.25 | 1
  WD123   |     KC    |  1.25  |  4.50 | 2 
  WD123   |     MK    |  1.25  |  4.25 | 1
  WD123   |     MK    |  1.25  |  4.50 | 2
```

I want to create the following:

```
item_code | whse_desc | Height1 | Height 2 | Width1 | Width2 | Window
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  WD123   |     KC    |   1.25  |    1.25  |  4.25  |   4.50 | ???
  WD123   |     MK    |   1.25  |    1.25  |  4.25  |   4.50 | ???
```

For every item_code, there are 2 rows that are returned (first record containing Window(1) and the second containing Window(2) dimensions). I am trying to combine the two rows to create one. When I use a group by, it wants to split the 2 rows apart due to the Window(value). I have tried using case statements, but I still end up with two rows. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: So how do you magically transformed from table 1 to table 2?

Comment: What are you expecting in the _Window_ column of your results?  The column where you have the ???.  Are you saying you don't want that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are expecting in the `Window` column (???) of your results.  Assuming you don't want that column here is a solution that joins the table to itself.  The first table in the join is looking for `window=1` and the second table (same table) is looking for `window=2`.

```
--demo setup
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1
go
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (item_code varchar(5), whse_desc varchar(2), Height decimal(5,2), Width decimal(5,2), Window int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (item_code, whse_desc, Height, Width, Window)
VALUES
    ('WD123', 'KC', 1.25, 4.25, 1),
    ('WD123', 'KC', 1.25, 4.50, 2),
    ('WD123', 'MK', 1.25, 4.25, 1),
    ('WD123', 'MK', 1.25, 4.50, 2)
;

--solution
SELECT t1.item_code
    ,t1.whse_desc
    ,t1.height AS height1
    ,t2.Height AS height2
    ,t1.Width AS width1
    ,t2.Width AS width2
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
    ON t2.item_code = t1.item_code
        AND t2.whse_desc = t1.whse_desc
        AND t1.Window = 1
        AND t2.Window = 2
```

---

```
| item_code | whse_desc | height1 | height2 | width1 | width2 |
|-----------|-----------|---------|---------|--------|--------|
| WD123     | KC        | 1.25    | 1.25    | 4.25   | 4.50   |
| WD123     | MK        | 1.25    | 1.25    | 4.25   | 4.50   |
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: @dstanton - you are welcome.